# Boolean field returning as True in django forms

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a very simple form

```
class IcraveSatisfiedForm(forms.Form):
    satisfied_or_not = forms.BooleanField(label="Was your Crave satisfied?")
    satisfier = forms.CharField(label="Satisfier")



    def clean_satisfier(self):
        satisfier = self.cleaned_data['satisfier']
        satisfied = self.cleaned_data['satisfied_or_not']
        if satisfied == True:
          if satisfier !='':
            try:
                user = User.objects.get(username__iexact = satisfier)
            except:
                user = None
            if not user :
                raise forms.ValidationError('The username is not valid')
            else:
                return user
          else:
            return None
```

I want to clean this form and check both the values that are being used.But for some reason
self.cleaned_data['satisfied_or_not'] always returns True. What am i doing wrong ?

EDIT:

I have tried this in my view as well

```
def my_craves(request,crave_id = None):
    craves = Icrave.objects.filter(person = request.user,satisfied_or_not = False)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if 'satisfied_or_not' in request.POST:
            my_craves_form =IcraveSatisfiedForm(request.POST,user = request.user)
            if my_craves_form.is_valid() :
                satisfied = my_craves_form.cleaned_data['satisfied_or_not']
                satisfier = my_craves_form.cleaned_data['satisfier']
```

It is still returning as True

Request.POST

```
<QueryDict: {u'csrfmiddlewaretoken': [u'21bdde0fdac2b18101e1c42ba2f92843'], u'satisfier': [u'admin'], u'satisfied_or_not': [u'Update']}>
```

I am using normal form for rendering the data

```
 my_craves_form = IcraveSatisfiedForm()
    return render( request, 'icrave/view/my_craves.html', {'craves' : craves,'my_craves_form':my_craves_form})
```

Comment: do you really have two fields with the same name?

Comment: No my BAD.. copied the wrong field

Comment: Could you show the value of request.POST?

Comment: how are you generating your form html? a check box shouldn't be returning a string...

Answer (score 1):

a `clean_FOO` is only for cleaning a single field, and should return the cleaned data, nothing else.

for validation across several fields, use the `clean` method, which should return the entire `cleaned_data` dict

see [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation/) for more

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your `request.POST`, `satisfied_or_not` should not be a string for a boolean field.

```
<QueryDict: {u'csrfmiddlewaretoken': [u'21bdde0fdac2b18101e1c42ba2f92843'], u'satisfier': [u'admin'], u'satisfied_or_not': [u'Update']}>
```

It looks like you might be using the name `satisfied_or_not` for your form submit button as well as the checkbox. For example:

```
<p><input type="submit" name="satisfied_or_not" value="Update" /></p>
```

If so, you need to change it to something like

```
<p><input type="submit" name="update" value="Update" /></p>
```

Comment: Even though the above was true , it is still returning true after changing it.

Comment: Could you update the value of `request.POST`, and show us your template?